# Is it possible to resize/add noise to a hidden layer during training?

Tags: conv-neural-network, feature-engineering, dropout

I'm working on class for a project where my basic idea is to create a "drop-in" layer, so similar to drop out, I'm thinking of adding hidden units that are sampled from the same weight distribution with probability p. The problem here is that the size of the neural network would probably keep growing dynamically as we train, right? I was wondering if there is anyway to achieve this, or something similar to this?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to do this instead of using drop-out? It's interesting, by I'm inclined to think if it isn't done, it may be because researchers tried it and found drop-out worked better.

Comment: I find it to be an interesting idea to explore. I just want to see how it turns out. I’m pretty sure someone’s tried it before like you have said. Do you have any idea how to overcome the above challenges?

Comment: If you couple this with dropout with probability p the expected number of hidden units will not change, if you don’t want to add dropout I don’t think there is a way to deal with the growing problem